# GCD debugDescription of serial queue value of locked key?

Tags: ios, objective-c, grand-central-dispatch

I am performing lots of data commit and data read operations on SQL database using GCD, I have created serial queue and to perform operations I am using `dispatch_async`.

Queue Creation Code:

```
  self.dataBaseQueue = dispatch_queue_create("com.myAPP.dataBaseQueue", DISPATCH_QUEUE_SERIAL);
```

Execution code

```
  dispatch_async(self.dataBaseQueue, codeblock);
```

codeblock contains database operation read or write.

Now when I log `debugDescription` of queue it's printing

```
OS_dispatch_queue: com.myAPP.dataBaseQueue[0x1cd58ae0] = { xrefcnt = 0x1, refcnt = 0x1, suspend_cnt = 0x0, **locked = 0**, target = com.apple.root.default-overcommit-priority[0x3d335300], width = 0x0, running = 0x0, barrier = 0 }
```

After some operations it's printing

```
OS_dispatch_queue: com.myAPP.dataBaseQueue[0x1cd58ae0] = { xrefcnt = 0x1, refcnt = 0x1, suspend_cnt = 0x0, **locked = 1**, target = com.apple.root.default-overcommit-priority[0x3d335300], width = 0x0, running = 0x0, barrier = 0 }
```

So what's meaning of `locked =1` and `locked =0`?

Comment: What is `debugDescription`? Is it output of dispatch_debug?

Comment: Yes it's like dispatch_debug.

Comment: You may find sources of libdispatch library helpful: http://libdispatch.macosforge.org/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As yurish pointed out the sources are available, but "let me google that for you" anyway, with some (hopefully helpful) added analysis.

First, some background... In [`object_internal.h`](http://libdispatch.macosforge.org/trac/browser/trunk/src/object_internal.h) you can find the following `#define`s:

```
#define DISPATCH_OBJECT_SUSPEND_LOCK            1u
#define DISPATCH_OBJECT_SUSPEND_INTERVAL        2u
#define DISPATCH_OBJECT_SUSPENDED(x) \
    ((x)->do_suspend_cnt >= DISPATCH_OBJECT_SUSPEND_INTERVAL)
```

This indicates that a single value is going to be used with these `#define`s in order to have it do double-duty as both a lock bit (in the LSB) and a suspend count (in the rest of the bits.)

Then, over in [`object.c`](http://libdispatch.macosforge.org/trac/browser/trunk/src/object.c) we can see where this debug message business is actually implemented:

```
size_t
_dispatch_object_debug_attr(dispatch_object_t dou, char* buf, size_t bufsiz)
{
        return snprintf(buf, bufsiz, "xrefcnt = 0x%x, refcnt = 0x%x, "
                        "suspend_cnt = 0x%x, locked = %d, ", dou._do->do_xref_cnt + 1,
                        dou._do->do_ref_cnt + 1,
                        dou._do->do_suspend_cnt / DISPATCH_OBJECT_SUSPEND_INTERVAL,
                        dou._do->do_suspend_cnt & 1);
}
```

Sure enough, we see that `suspend_cnt` corresponds to `dou._do->do_suspend_cnt / DISPATCH_OBJECT_SUSPEND_INTERVAL` and `locked` corresponds to `dou._do->do_suspend_cnt & 1` so it's easy to conclude that, yes, `do_suspend_cnt` is doing this double duty hinted at by the aforementioned `#define`s.

Now, without getting into too much detail we can observe in the source that `do_suspend_cnt` is referenced in only a handful of places in [`queue.c`](http://libdispatch.macosforge.org/trac/browser/trunk/src/queue.c). It's mentioned in initialization of queue structures. It's also used by the `barrier` calls but only in terms of incrementing and decrementing it by `DISPATCH_OBJECT_SUSPEND_INTERVAL`, so that's not interesting (at least not with respect to the lock bit -- one might consider it interesting that barrier dispatch is implemented by suspending the queue until the barrier invoke returns, but that's not what OP asked).

The remaining mentions I see are in `_dispatch_wakeup` which appears to atomically set the lock bit before taking the next work item off of the queue (makes sense, right? Don't take things off the queue from more than one place simultaneously) and then again in `_dispatch_queue_invoke` subtracting the lock bit, seemingly to balance the setting of it in `_dispatch_wakeup`. Lastly, we see it mentioned in `_dispatch_queue_cleanup2` which looks (on the surface) like one-time teardown work for the main dispatch queue.

So there you have it. The appearance of `locked =` in the debug description is exposing the state of an internal lock bit that `libdispatch` appears to be using to protect its internal data structures from concurrent mutation. It is probably not of any consequence to you as a user of `libdispatch`.